# Angular Reactive form : Not able to bind action in table

Tags: angular

I am unable to add radio button in Table using Angular 2+. 
If there is no radio button(action), it's rendering properly but once i tried to add action to it, it's throwing error.

Reff Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-form-validation-h96cge?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Please share your feedback.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use FormArray in HTML to indicate that this is array 
**formArrayName="address"**
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-form-validation-5mxbb8)